# GC goes mad with GC_CONCURRENT when running below code

Tags: android, garbage-collection, android-listview, android-viewpager

I am pulling contact name and thumbnail by phone number with below method.
When it runs GC goes mad. Methos is in a utility class and gets called from an adapter to populate a listview. List has more than 20 items/numbers to query contacts db.

I am new to Java and Android I can't seem to figure out what is wrong, or if nothing is wrong how to optimize it.

Main problem is that listview is in a ViewPager and this make horizontal scrolling quite slow and jerky.

```
public static Contact getContact(Context ctx, String phoneNumber)
{
    String contactName = "";
    Long contactId= 0L;
    Bitmap contactPhoto =null;
    ContentResolver localContentResolver = ctx.getContentResolver();
    Cursor contactLookupCursor =  
       localContentResolver.query(
                Uri.withAppendedPath(PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, 
                Uri.encode(phoneNumber)), 
                new String[] {PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME, BaseColumns._ID}, 
                null, 
                null, 
                null);
    try {
    while(contactLookupCursor.moveToNext()){
        contactName = contactLookupCursor.getString(contactLookupCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME));
        contactId = contactLookupCursor.getLong(contactLookupCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(BaseColumns._ID));
        Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, contactId);
        InputStream input = ContactsContract.Contacts.openContactPhotoInputStream(ctx.getContentResolver(), uri);
        contactPhoto = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        }
    }
    finally {
    contactLookupCursor.close();
    } 

    return new Contact(contactName,contactId,contactPhoto);
}
```

Here is a sample from logcat

```
 10-16 22:05:39.745: D/dalvikvm(29171): GC_CO

NCURRENT freed 322K, 6% free 15200K/16071K, paused 1ms+11ms
10-16 22:05:40.005: D/dalvikvm(29171): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1428K, 12% free 14170K/16071K, paused 15ms
10-16 22:05:40.080: D/dalvikvm(29171): GC_CONCURRENT freed 70K, 12% free 14303K/16071K, paused 1ms+8ms
10-16 22:05:40.230: D/dalvikvm(29171): GC_CONCURRENT freed 305K, 10% free 14476K/16071K, paused 2ms+1ms
10-16 22:05:40.315: D/dalvikvm(29171): GC_EXPLICIT freed 169K, 11% free 14348K/16071K, paused 4ms+12ms
10-16 22:05:40.660: D/dalvikvm(29171): GC_CONCURRENT freed 329K, 10% free 14495K/16071K, paused 1ms+3ms
10-16 22:05:40.850: D/dalvikvm(29171): GC_CONCURRENT freed 543K, 11% free 14416K/16071K, paused 1ms+1ms
10-16 22:05:40.980: D/dalvikvm(29171): GC_CONCURRENT freed 380K, 10% free 14497K/16071K, paused 1ms+4ms
10-16 22:05:41.135: D/dalvikvm(29171): GC_CONCURRENT freed 521K, 11% free 14440K/16071K, paused 2ms+2ms
10-16 22:05:41.375: D/dalvikvm(29171): GC_CONCURRENT freed 406K, 11% free 14444K/16071K, paused 1ms+2ms
10-16 22:05:41.470: D/dalvikvm(29171): GC_CONCURRENT freed 270K, 10% free 14583K/16071K, paused 2ms+2ms
10-16 22:05:41.680: D/dalvikvm(29171): GC_CONCURRENT freed 290K, 9% free 14774K/16071K, paused 2ms+4ms
10-16 22:05:41.760: D/dalvikvm(29171): GC_EXPLICIT freed 98K, 9% free 14749K/16071K, paused 3ms+2ms
10-16 22:05:41.900: D/dalvikvm(29171): GC_CONCURRENT freed 199K, 7% free 14973K/16071K, paused 1ms+3ms
10-16 22:05:42.070: D/dalvikvm(29171): GC_CONCURRENT freed 277K, 7% free 15086K/16071K, paused 1ms+3ms
10-16 22:05:42.335: D/dalvikvm(29171): GC_CONCURRENT freed 416K, 6% free 15158K/16071K, paused 1ms+3ms
10-16 22:05:42.430: D/dalvikvm(29171): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1235K, 11% free 14315K/16071K, paused 1ms+2ms
10-16 22:05:42.525: D/dalvikvm(29171): GC_CONCURRENT freed 452K, 11% free 14364K/16071K, paused 2ms+3ms
10-16 22:05:42.925: D/dalvikvm(29171): GC_CONCURRENT freed 371K, 11% free 14445K/16071K, paused 2ms+1ms
10-16 22:05:43.045: D/dalvikvm(29171): GC_CONCURRENT freed 495K, 11% free 14335K/16071K, paused 2ms+2ms
10-16 22:05:43.190: D/dalvikvm(29171): GC_CONCURRENT freed 295K, 11% free 14431K/16071K, paused 2ms+3ms
10-16 22:05:43.315: D/dalvikvm(29171): GC_EXPLICIT freed 236K, 11% free 14329K/16071K, paused 2ms+3ms
10-16 22:05:43.575: D/dalvikvm(29171): GC_CONCURRENT freed 316K, 11% free 14436K/16071K, paused 1ms+1ms
10-16 22:05:43.660: D/dalvikvm(29171): GC_CONCURRENT freed 281K, 10% free 14585K/16071K, paused 1ms+2ms
10-16 22:05:43.905: D/dalvikvm(29171): GC_CONCURRENT freed 309K, 9% free 14754K/16071K, paused 2ms+3ms
10-16 22:05:44.070: D/dalvikvm(29171): GC_CONCURRENT freed 270K, 7% free 14968K/16071K, paused 2ms+2ms
10-16 22:05:44.300: D/dalvikvm(29171): GC_CONCURRENT freed 265K, 7% free 15103K/16071K, paused 1ms+4ms
10-16 22:05:44.495: D/dalvikvm(29171): GC_CONCURRENT freed 400K, 6% free 15176K/16071K, paused 2ms+5ms
10-16 22:05:44.695: D/dalvikvm(29171): GC_CONCURRENT freed 447K, 6% free 15137K/16071K, paused 3ms+6ms
10-16 22:05:44.780: D/dalvikvm(29171): GC_EXPLICIT freed 354K, 7% free 15037K/16071K, paused 2ms+3ms
10-16 22:05:45.075: D/dalvikvm(29171): GC_CONCURRENT freed 422K, 7% free 15104K/16071K, paused 1ms+2ms
10-16 22:05:45.140: D/AbsListView(29171): Get MotionRecognitionManager
10-16 22:05:45.340: D/dalvikvm(29171): GC_CONCURRENT freed 293K, 6% free 15252K/16071K, paused 2ms+6ms
10-16 22:05:45.340: D/AbsListView(29171): [unregisterDoubleTapMotionListener]
10-16 22:05:45.340: I/MotionRecognitionManager(29171):   .unregisterListener : / listener count = 0->0, listener=android.widget.AbsListView$4@41a600c8
10-16 22:05:45.530: D/dalvikvm(29171): GC_CONCURRENT freed 849K, 8% free 14799K/16071K, paused 2ms+7ms
10-16 22:05:45.720: D/dalvikvm(29171): GC_CONCURRENT freed 394K, 8% free 14908K/16071K, paused 3ms+5ms
10-16 22:05:45.940: D/dalvikvm(29171): GC_CONCURRENT freed 452K, 8% free 14845K/16071K, paused 2ms+3ms
10-16 22:05:46.085: D/dalvikvm(29171): GC_CONCURRENT freed 374K, 8% free 14917K/16071K, paused 1ms+3ms
10-16 22:05:46.335: D/dalvikvm(29171): GC_CONCURRENT freed 457K, 8% free 14892K/16071K, paused 1ms+2ms
10-16 22:05:46.390: D/dalvikvm(29171): GC_EXPLICIT freed 148K, 8% free 14870K/16071K, paused 1ms+3ms
10-16 22:05:46.550: D/dalvikvm(29171): GC_CONCURRENT freed 415K, 8% free 14844K/16071K, paused 2ms+4ms
10-16 22:05:46.680: D/dalvikvm(29171): GC_CONCURRENT freed 223K, 7% free 15046K/16071K, paused 2ms+3ms
10-16 22:05:46.825: D/AbsListView(29171): Get MotionRecognitionManager
10-16 22:05:46.965: D/dalvikvm(29171): GC_CONCURRENT freed 346K, 6% free 15124K/16071K, paused 1ms+3ms
10-16 22:05:46.965: D/AbsListView(29171): [unregisterDoubleTapMotionListener]
10-16 22:05:46.965: I/MotionRecognitionManager(29171):   .unregisterListener : / listener count = 0->0, listener=android.widget.AbsListView$4@41a49d90
10-16 22:05:47.095: D/dalvikvm(29171): GC_CONCURRENT freed 755K, 9% free 14758K/16071K, paused 2ms+5ms
10-16 22:05:47.375: D/dalvikvm(29171): GC_CONCURRENT freed 416K, 8% free 14835K/16071K, paused 2ms+5ms
10-16 22:05:47.565: D/dalvikvm(29171): GC_CONCURRENT freed 415K, 8% free 14888K/16071K, paused 2ms+5ms
10-16 22:05:47.975: D/dalvikvm(29171): GC_CONCURRENT freed 475K, 8% free 14814K/16071K, paused 2ms+3ms
10-16 22:05:48.105: D/dalvikvm(29171): GC_CONCURRENT freed 411K, 8% free 14867K/16071K, paused 2ms+3ms
10-16 22:05:48.155: D/dalvikvm(29171): GC_EXPLICIT freed 114K, 9% free 14760K/16071K, paused 2ms+4ms
10-16 22:05:48.280: D/dalvikvm(29171): GC_CONCURRENT freed 284K, 8% free 14902K/16071K, paused 1ms+3ms
10-16 22:05:48.435: D/dalvikvm(29171): GC_CONCURRENT freed 332K, 7% free 15000K/16071K, paused 3ms+4ms
10-16 22:05:48.655: D/dalvikvm(29171): GC_CONCURRENT freed 415K, 7% free 14985K/16071K, paused 1ms+2ms
10-16 22:05:48.805: D/dalvikvm(29171): GC_CONCURRENT freed 451K, 7% free 15002K/16071K, paused 3ms+5ms
10-16 22:05:49.150: D/dalvikvm(29171): GC_CONCURRENT freed 417K, 7% free 14985K/16071K, paused 1ms+2ms
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are iterating over an entire result set, creating bitmaps for all the thumbnails, then throwing all those results away except the last one. If you only want the last one, just process the last one.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to do the cursor lookup when the Activity starts and save the thumbnail and phone number to an object, then have a list of these objects in a cache.

Then when you are displaying the ListView you can read from your local cache instead of doing a database lookup for each item each time.

---

Also wouldn't it be better to create a query that returns you all contacts, then query this cursor result for the phone number and therefore the row?